# Dots and Spacing in Table of Contents/List of Figures, etc. with `hyperref` loaded

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, tocloft

I'm using the `hyperref` package and am unable to load `tocloft`. I've tried everything including a *voodoo ritual involving a rubber chicken* to get the two to shake hands.

Is there a work around to get dots in the table of contents, list of figures/tables? Also, in my list of figures/tables I have the depth set to section, so I see an overlap-spacing problem with the numbering and the caption title. Is there a simple way to correct this spacing?

```
 \documentclass[psamsfonts,10pt,reqno,letterpaper]{amsbook}

\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{section}{chapter}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
\counterwithin{table}{chapter}

 \usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\ChRuleWidth{1.618pt}
\ChTitleVar{\raggedright  \huge }
\ChNameVar{\raggedleft  \Huge }

\usepackage[bookmarksdepth=subsection,plainpages=false]{hyperref}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

 \listoftables

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
stuff
\end{tabular}
\caption{stuff}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: This really doesn't deserve a downvote. Here on TeX.sx, it is generally expected that downvotes are reserved for things that are actually *wrong* and/or *bad*. This question is fine by that standard.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the following setting chapters have their dots and **hyperref** doesn't complain.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftdot}{\normalfont.} % don't inherit the \bfseries attribute
\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{4.5}   % same spacing as for sections

\usepackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: I just added a minimal example. I still get errors even with your work-around. ;(

Comment: Sorry, tocloft is not compatible with **amsbook**, which *never* uses dots in the table of contents and similar places. Use the normal **book** class.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work immediately after `\usepackage{amsbook}`

```
\makeatletter
\def\@tocline#1#2#3#4#5#6#7{\relax
\ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth % then omit
\else
\par \addpenalty\@secpenalty\addvspace{#2}%
\begingroup \hyphenpenalty\@M
\@ifempty{#4}{%
  \@tempdima\csname r@tocindent\number#1\endcsname\relax
}{%
  \@tempdima#4\relax
}%
\parindent\z@ \leftskip#3\relax \advance\leftskip\@tempdima\relax
\rightskip\@pnumwidth plus4em \parfillskip-\@pnumwidth
#5\leavevmode\hskip-\@tempdima #6\nobreak\relax
\ifnum#1<0\hfill\else\dotfill\fi\hbox to\@pnumwidth{\@tocpagenum{#7}}\par
\nobreak
\endgroup
\fi}
\makeatother
```